# Gigabit connection between 2 computers

Tags: networking, gigabit-ethernet

I am trying to set up a connection between 2 pc's. It's a direct cable connection. The problem that I am having is that the connection isn't gigabit. I know both network cards support gigabit. I checked in the device settings and in one pc I can see in the Speed & Duplex the 1Gbps option but on the other pc I can't see that option despite the fact that the network card is gigabit.

I have quite some files to copy from one pc onto another and I really need a good connection between them. I can't really remove the hard drive because it would void the warranty.

Could this be a driver issue or a cable issue? On both pc's I have windows 8.

The network card on the pc that doesn't have the 1 gbps option is an Atheros ar8161 card.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most probable cause is the cable. If you have a standard CAT5 cable you might be lucky, but getting hold of a CAT6 cable will most likely make both computers switch automatically to gigabit.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. It worked with a cat5e cable or something like that though.

Comment: good to hear it worked!

Comment: *"I am quite sure it is ..."* - Something like *"The most probable cause is ..."* sounds less pompous (unless that really is your intent).

Comment: I am most sorry for that tone. These are mistakes that happen when one is not native english speaker. Not intended at all, thanks for the correction, much appreciated.

Comment: No problem, as I assumed that English may not have been your first language because of the umlaut in your surname.  Another consideration for rephrasing (from a guide to technical writing that I read a very long time ago) is that the use of the first person (e.g. "I" or "we") should be avoided if possible.